# Retrieving the query strings from the URL

Tags: javascript, c#

I am navigating from one page in to other pages, while navigating I am passing two query parameters in the javascript as

```
 var redirect_page = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/GUI/ReviewNEW.aspx") %>'+"?testDate=" + lDate;
 window.location = redirect_page;
```

So the passed date is in the URL looks like

[image]

In the called page ReviewNEW.aspx.cs, I need to retrieve the query parameter testDate. I am using

```
private string l_Date = Request.QueryString["testDate"].ToString();
```

I am not sure if this will be converting in to `10/14/2016` so I can use this value in the select statement.

Comment: Can you print the value of redirect_page on console?

Comment: you could replace `%2F` with `/` if needed

Comment: @Rahul I just gave an alert statement to see how the value of the  testDate is passed

Comment: @trx I am sorry I can not see that alert statement here. Is it in the image, if yes, can you print it in the question. I am unable to open the images of stackoverflow. Some firewall issue.

Comment: @Rahul This is the value we get for the testDate in URL 10%2F14%2F2016 I want them to be converted in to 10/14/2016 in the called page ReviewNEW.aspx.cs to do further processing.

Comment: @trx does the below answer solves the problem?

Comment: Yes it did solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("12%2F10%2F2011+10%3A22%3A11");
```

Gives

```
"12/10/2011 10:22:11"
```